# How to use file relative path in xml

Tags: java, xml, relative-path

I have xml files in certain folders in my project, i want to read them by using folder level(../) hierarchy which is relative path. The below is my folder structure:

**BasePath:**

E:SDC-Build\SRDM2.3.0.6904.10\SRDM\Svr

a)tomcat

b)Idp -- >Idpserver-->idp -->WEB-INF->**service.xml**

c)Idp -- >Idpserver-->conf->attribute-resolver.xml

The above a, b, c are under above given base path.

I have the **service.xml** like below

but the above given path is not working, could any body please correct me if i gave the wrong path.

Comment: "Not working" means exactly what? (What error message from which tool?)

Comment: Resource D:\SDC-Builds\SRDM2.3.0.6904.10\SRDM\Svr\tomcat\.\IdP\IdPserver\conf\attribute-resolver.xml does not exist.

Comment: a)tomcat and b)Idp folders are in the same folder calles Svr, but i do not know why it is going to take tomcat folder...